# What's $\arccos(x) + \arccos(y)$ equal to?

Tags: trigonometry

I'd like to know whether there exists any additive properties of the $\arccos$ function. In particular, whether $\arccos(x) + \arccos(y)$ tells us anything about $\arccos(x+y)$ or just $x + y$.

P.S. I am aware that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(y) = \arccos(xy - \sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - y^2)})$. But are there any other properties of $\arccos$ that do not involve multiplication? If not, suppose we are summing up a lot of $\arccos$, are there any concentration property to it?

Comment: do you have a specific sum in mind?

Comment: You meant $arccos(x) +arccos( y) = arccos(xy - \sqrt{(1 - x^2)(1 - y^2)})$?

Comment: Just edited the question! Should be $arccos(x) + arccos(y) = arccos(xy - \sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})$

Comment: Your assertion is not necessarily true.  Let $~\alpha = \arccos(x) + \arccos(y).~$  Then, while it is true that $~\cos(\alpha)~$ must equal $~\displaystyle \left[ ~xy - \sqrt{ ~\left( ~1 - x^2\right) ~\left( ~1 - y^2\right)~} ~\right] ~$ it is not true that $~\alpha~$ must necessarily be an element of $~[0,\pi].$

Comment: As @user2661923 has mentioned, the full formula should be $\arccos(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})$ if $[x=y=1\lor x\sqrt{1-x^2}+y\sqrt{1-y^2}>0]$, and $2\pi-\arccos(xy-\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)})$ if $[(x\ne1\lor y\ne 1)\land x\sqrt{1-x^2}+y\sqrt{1-y^2}\le0]$.